# What is idiomatic code?

Tags: c#, idioms

I'd be interested in some before-and-after c# examples, some non-idiomatic vs idiomatic examples. Non-c# examples would be fine as well if they get the idea across. Thanks.

Comment: [Hidden features of C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9033/4830) is full of idiomatic C#. Not all of it mind you, but many of the simple one-liners with a high number of upvotes could be considered idiomatic. And some answers describe the non-idiomatic alternatives as well.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Idiomatic means following the conventions of the language.  You want to find the easiest and most common ways of accomplishing a task rather than porting your knowledge from a different language.

non-idiomatic python using a loop with append:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
newlist = []
for i in mylist:
    newlist.append(i * 2)
```

idiomatic python using a list comprehension:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
newlist = [(i * 2) for i in mylist]
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the top answer... the original poster asked for C# examples and this is Python. JacquesB's answer below answers the question that was asked.

Comment: @AndyPreston The question does mention "Non-c# examples would be fine as well if they get the idea across.". I think Corey Goldberg answered it in very simple and easy to understand manner.

Answer (score 46):

Some examples:

**Resource management**, non idiomatic:

```
string content;
StreamReader sr = null;
try {
    File.OpenText(path);
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
finally {
    if (sr != null) {
        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

Idiomatic:

```
string content;
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) {
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

**Iteration**, non idiomatic:

```
for (int i=0;i<list.Count; i++) {
   DoSomething(list[i]);
}
```

Also non-idiomatic:

```
IEnumerator e = list.GetEnumerator();
do {
   DoSomenthing(e.Current);
} while (e.MoveNext());
```

Idiomatic:

```
foreach (Item item in list) {
   DoSomething(item);
}
```

**Filtering**, non-idiomatic:

```
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
for (int num in list1) {
  if (num>100) list2.Add(num);
}
```

idiomatic:

```
var list2 = list1.Where(num=>num>100);
```

Comment: The braces are idiomatic Java ;-)

Answer (score 22):

Idiomatic code is code that does a common task in the common way for your language.  It's similar to a design pattern, but at a much smaller scale.  Idioms differ widely by language.  One idiom in C# might be to use an iterator to iterate through a collection rather than looping through it.  Other languages without iterators might rely on the loop idiom.

Answer (score 7):

Practically speaking, it means writing code in a consistent way, i.e. all developers who work on your code base should follow the same conventions when writing similar code constructs.

So the idiomatic way is the way that matches the style of the other code, non-idiomatic way means you are writing the kind of function but in a different way.

e.g. if you are looping a certain number of items, you could write the loop in several ways:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)

for (int i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++)

for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; ++i)
```

etc

What is most important is that the chosen style is used consistently.  That way people become very familiar and confident with how to use it, and when you spy a usage which looks different it can be a sign of a mistake being introduced, perhaps an off by one error, e.g.

```
for (int i = 1; i < itemCount; i++)
```

Comment: I guess I thought idiomatic meant "the best way" as opposed to just an arbitrary standard. But I guess a best way is subject to context.

Answer (score 7):

In PHP I sometimes encounter code like:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $trimmed[] = trim($value);
}
return $trimmed;
```

Which idiomatically can be implemented with:

```
return array_map('trim', $array);
```